# CentOS Firewall Contingency

Tags: centos, firewall, centos7, firewalld

What happens if the firewalld service fails to start on CentOS 7?

Will the network still function? Will firewall rules still be partially enforced?

If the firewall rules are not enforced, is there a way to shut off network services automatically?

Answer (score 1):

1. If firewalld service fail to start, that means you do not have any firewall on your system unless otherwise iptables is running. (some administrator like to stop the firewalld service and install the iptabls service instead).
2. Yes, Network will be functional.
3. No, no partial rules enforced.
4. In that case, you can write a script, which will check the firewall status(systemctl status firewalld.service) and if the firewall status is dead/not running than it will stop the network service(systemctl stop network.service).